# Why does greater than and unequal operators work even though only less than and equal operator has been overloaded

Tags: python, operator-overloading

I'm currently looking into how Python does its operator overloading. So far I find it much more appealing than in C++ especially in term of operators such as `*` (or similar arithmetic operators) that has to handle an operation that can be applied both right to left (2*x) and left to right (x*2) in some way.

I have the following class as a test:

```
from math import sqrt

class Vector3:
    def __init__(self, x,y,z):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.z = z

    def __repr__(self):
        return 'Vector3(x=%d, y=%d, z=%d)' % (self.x, self.y, self.z)

    def __str__(self):
        return '[x: %d, y: %d, z: %d]' % (self.x, self.y, self.z)

    def length(self):
        return sqrt(self.x**2 + self.y**2 + self.z**2)

    def __add__(self, vector):
        return Vector3(self.x + vector.x, self.y + vector.y, self.z + vector.z)

    def __sub__(self, vector):
        return Vector3(self.x - vector.x, self.y - vector.y, self.z - vector.z)

    def __mul__(self, scalar):
        return Vector3(self.x * scalar, self.y * scalar, self.z * scalar)

    __rmul__ = __mul__ # Right multiplication equals left multiplication (if this defers, __rmul__ has to be overwritten and defined manually)

    def __eq__(self, vector):
        return (self.x == vector.x and self.y == vector.y and self.z == vector.z)

    def __lt__(self, vector):
        return self.length() < vector.length()

    @staticmethod
    def compareAndPrint(vector1, vector2):
        if vector1 == vector2: return 'v1 == v2 since len(v1) = %f == %f = len(v2)' % (vector1.length(), vector2.length())
        elif vector1 < vector2: return 'v1 < v2 since len(v1) = %f < %f = len(v2)' % (vector1.length(), vector2.length())
        elif vector1 > vector2: return 'v1 > v2 since len(v1) = %f > %f = len(v2)' % (vector1.length(), vector2.length())

v1 = Vector3(1,2,3)
v2 = Vector3(0,-1,1)
v3 = v1 + v2
v4 = v3 - v1
v5 = v1 * 2
v6 = 2 * v1
print(v1)
print(v2)
print(v3)
print(v4)
print(v5)
print(v6)

print(Vector3.compareAndPrint(v1,v2))
print(Vector3.compareAndPrint(v2,v1))
print(Vector3.compareAndPrint(v1,v1))
```

I'm simply adding more and more operators to my custom class and observing how those behave. You might have noticed two things (based on my question in the title):

- `__gt__` is not overloaded and
- `Vector3.compareAndPrint(...)` function uses the `>` (greater than) operator

For some reason I get the output I would expect as if I have overloaded `>`:

```
[x: 1, y: 2, z: 3]
[x: 0, y: -1, z: 1]
[x: 1, y: 1, z: 4]
[x: 0, y: -1, z: 1]
[x: 2, y: 4, z: 6]
[x: 2, y: 4, z: 6]
v1 > v2 since len(v1) = 3.741657 > 1.414214 = len(v2)
v1 < v2 since len(v1) = 1.414214 < 3.741657 = len(v2)
v1 == v2 since len(v1) = 3.741657 == 3.741657 = len(v2)
```

Does Python handle this automatically or have I done something that I haven't noticed to make this work? The only thing that comes into my mind is that Python takes the inverse of `<` and at the same time adds exclusion for the `==` since the inverse of `>` is `<=` and not just `<`.

The same thing applies to the `!=` (unequal) operator. Here I'm 99% sure that Python inverts the overloaded `==` operator.

Comment: Why not throw in some `print`s to see which methods get invoked and when?

Comment: I have the prints. Please see the end of the post and in particular the comparison (v1, v2) and (v2, v1). Or do you mean something else?

Comment: No, I mean put some *inside* `__lt__` and `__eq__` to see when they're called, and with what parameters.

Comment: Ah, thanks for the advice. +1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most binary operators in Python can be overloaded by either operand. There's one method for the left operand to define, like `__add__` for addition, and one for the right operand, like `__radd__`. The only one I recall that can only be overloaded by one operand is `in`, which the right side must define.

For comparisons, instead of `__gt__` and `__rgt__` methods, `__rgt__` is just `__lt__`. That means that when you do `left_thing > right_thing` and `left_thing` doesn't know what to do, Python tries `right_thing < left_thing`. Since you've implemented `__lt__`, this works.

Note that Python will not try anything involving `__le__`, `__ge__`, or `__eq__` if `__gt__` and `__lt__` fail.

Comment: Marking this as the answer because of the neat tip at the end. Need to wait 4 minutes for that though. LOL

Answer (score 2):

This is a bit of the python data model that many seem to not understand.  To trace this through the documentation we need to start with binary arithmetic operations (`__mul__`, `__add__`, etc.).

We notice that there is a [`__mul__`](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__mul__) and a `__rmul__` method.  The difference is described in docs under the [latter](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__rmul__):

> These methods are called to implement the binary arithmetic operations (+, -, *, /, %, divmod(), pow(), **, <<, >>, &, ^, |) with reflected (swapped) operands. **These functions are only called if the left operand does not support the corresponding operation and the operands are of different types.**

Now when we look at the documentation for [rich comparison methods](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__lt__):

> There are no swapped-argument versions of these methods (to be used when the left argument does not support the operation but the right argument does); rather, `__lt__()` and `__gt__()` are each other’s reflection

So, what's happening in your case is that since `__gt__` hasn't been overloaded, python actually swaps the order of the arguments and calls `__lt__`.  Pretty neat.

---

FWIW, if you want to construct a class that is orderable with other instances of the class, the [`functools.total_ordering`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functools.html#functools.total_ordering) decorator can be *super* helpful.  You just supply `__lt__` and `__eq__` and the decorator supplies the rest.

Comment: Will take a look at the `functools.total_ordering`. +1

Comment: Btw I have a small question - is it possible to overload an operator multiple times with different arguments. In C++ it's quite simply but in Python since you don't provide a type for the argument I don't seem to be able to grasp the technique of how to implement it. For example `vector * vector` should return a scalar but `vector * scalar` and `scalar * vector` should return a `vector`.

Comment: @rbaleksandar -- C++'s overloading is a lot more complex than pythons.  In C++ you can overload based on type and number of arguments -- In python you can only have one function that doesn't care about type (and in some cases the number of arguments).  You can use some functions to check and then delegate to other functions however -- e.g.  `if isinstance(x, Vector): return self._vector_add(x, y)`

Comment: Yeah, that's what I said - in C++ this thing in particular is quite simple. :D That check of whether the argument is an instance of a specific class though is sweet. Thanks a lot!